# IOS swipe to delete and multiple row editing cause the button names set to default

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

Well I am using multiple selection during editing and swipe to delete functions at the same time.. what I want is when select button is clicked, change its title to Cancel and make the color red..

and what happens with me is titles still remain as `edit` and `done`.  What am I doing wrong?

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {

    if (editing) {
        self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
        self.editButtonItem.title = @"Cancel";
        self.editButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
     } else {
        self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = NO;
        self.editButtonItem.title = @"Select";
        self.editButtonItem.tintColor = nil;
    }

    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = editing;

}
```

Comment: no one?? lol.. must be confusing

Comment: yeah, ur question is not clear enough! What is "editButtonItem"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not so sure what are tripping with. Your question is not clear enough. I'll take a stab here and suggest u use this delegate method.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
   titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return @"New name for swipe button";
}
```